# Reading Comma separated strings

Tags: c

i want to read a string containing integers and store all integers in some integer variables.
e.g

```
 str[]="12,23,45"
```

can anyone please help me out.
i tried for a space separated integers..

```
            #include<string.h>
            #include<stdio.h>
            int main()
            {
                char buffer[]="12,34,56";
                int x,y,z;
                if(sscanf(buffer,"%d%d%d",&x,&y,&z)>2);
                {

                    printf("%d\n",x);
                    printf("%d\n",y);
                    printf("%d\n",z);
                }

            return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your precious time.
stay happy.

Comment: Where you reading from? File or stdin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there!

`sscanf()` requires you to give the format of the expected string to be parsed.

You have commas between numbers... Just try to add commas between the `%d`...

```
  "%d,%d,%d"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**: use a combination of standard library functions such as `strtok()` and `atoi()`, or `sscanf()`. With these tools, you'll figure it out in no time!

**Option 2**: roll out your own function! It's a nice thinking excerise :).